# Should I submit different research statement in different advertised postdoc positions

Tags: research-process, postdocs

I am a Phd student in applied mathematics. Recently I submitted PhD thesis and started applying for postdoc positions. There I have to submit research statement. My question is that should I submit same research statement everywhere or modify my research statement according to the requirement in the advertised position.

Comment: Can do either one. The point is to get somebody interested in you and to show that you fit the job description. If your universal statement works for that, there is no need to change it but if you see that university X is hiring in field A, you are proficient in both A and B, and your universal statement puts emphasis on B, I would rewrite it for X.

Comment: @fedja Why not write that as an answer?